# Skip a number of empty arrays - Problems in states and console

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

The data is obtained in the getRecommend / getPopular function, then the results are written to the appropriate states and I propagate them to another component, the question is, when displaying these 2 states, I first have a bunch of empty arrays, is this normal or not, if not, how fix?

There are about 10-15 lines in the console [], then the data comes

```
const {userId} = useParams();
    const {page} = useParams();

    const [recommend, setRecommend] = useState([]);
    const [popular, setPopular] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fun = async () => {
            try {
                let result = await getRecommend(userId, 6)
                if (result) {
                    setRecommend(result)
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("err")
            }
        }
        fun()
    }, [userId])
```

Comment: Hey there, can you explain where the console.log is happening? Do you mean the one that's consoling the error? Or somewhere else?

Comment: You have to show more code. The entire component and where do you use it.

Comment: @AmitMaraj after useEffect

Comment: @KonradLinkowski it's full then I just map the data

Comment: Components in react rerender multiple times.  It's normal that the data is empty for the first time it renders. 10-15? Maybe if you have 10 - 15 of this component. How could we know if you don't want to show the code?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski  hmmm Can you post code in the comments?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you have state with empty arrays, It's normal. You can improve UX by adding [skeleton](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-skeleton/)

In addition, you can reduce the number of calling API (as well as rendering) by checking more conditions to fetching like below:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const fun = async () => {
            try {
                let result = await getRecommend(userId, 6)
                if (result) {
                    setRecommend(result)
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("err")
            }
        }
        if(userId && page => 0){
           fun()
        }
    }, [userId])
```